# No luck getting most recent entry in sub-select: ORA-00904: invalid identifier, and ORA-06553: wrong number or types of arguments in call

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I've seen many posts about this subject but none of the solutions solved my problem.

In a nutshell, I have a users table and a user_history table. Each user can have 0 or more user_history entries. The user_history table has a status column. All I want to do is get a list of users and the value of the status column for their most recent user_history entry. And I can't get it to work. I've tried:

```
select u.id, u.name, 
(select status from (select status, rownum as rn from user_history uh where uh.user_id = u.id    
order by created_date desc) where rn = 1) status
from users u;
```

This gives me a "ORA-00904: invalid identifier, u.id" error. From what I've read, Oracle does not allow you to access the outer-select 'u.id' from within a sub-sub-select (the one with rownum). From the first sub-select it works fine but as I said, I can have n entries in user_history, I only need the most recent.

I've also tried using an inner join:

```
select u.id, u.name, h.status
from users u
inner join (select user_id, status, rownum as rn from user_history where user_id = u.id order by created_date desc) h on u.id = h.user_id where h.rn = 1;
```

This gives me the dreaded "ORA-06553: wrong number or types of arguments in call to u" ... which I tried fixing by using distinct but to no avail.

I've also tried using row_number(), over and partition ... other types of inner joins with select ... nothing gets me the data I need.

Can someone give me a hand with this (seemingly) simple query?

Comment: Both of your queries are wrongly formed

Comment: You mean the syntax is wrong? I may have made an editinf error. Can you tell me where the error is?

Comment: Just look at the answers below.

Comment: Also I can just tell you that when you use `rownum` and `order by` in the same query - expect the unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In old days query would look something like this

```
select 
    u.id, 
    u.name, 
    uh.status
from 
    users u 
        inner join
    (select 
         user_id, 
         status 
     from 
         user_history h 
     where 
         created_date = (select 
                             max(created_date) 
                         from 
                             user_history d 
                         where 
                             h.user_id = d.user_id)
     ) uh
         on u.id = uh.user_id;
```

What you have here is a correlated subquery that will get you latest date in history for the user. It is going to execute for each row so it is a bit slow performer. And you Join it with your user table to get your status.
I haven't tested it but it looks right.

Comment: This is giving me a "ORA-00904: h.user_id: invalid identifier" error, on the last line, "on u.id = h.user_id". Is there access to "h" from the inner-join, seeing that "h" is created select within the inner-join?

Comment: For what it's worth, I ran this against my fake data, and the results looked good

Comment: I just accepted the answer. Thanks so much, you are a true sql guru. Unfortunately it didn't completely solve my problem. I simplified the query to make it easier to understand. What I left out was another, quite complex "column" in the "select" clause, so now it's "select u.id, u.name, uh.status, (select count(*) from table2, table3, table4 ...)", and two more tables in the "from" and "where" clause. When I add them back, I am again getting the "ORA-06553" error. But that wasn't part of the original question. I guess I'll have to refactor with that with inner-join as well. Sigh.

Comment: @RobertBowen When query gets that complex, I suggest to "prepare" the table in your inline query. And then join the end result. And don't try to write all in once. Add your tables to the join one by one. You got the right result then add next one. And no, I am not true sql guru. What you had in your question was just obvious to me

Comment: Sound advice. That's the way I usually do it. And in fact with this last piece, it's so complex I have to add it bit by bit.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?  It would also eliminate the scalar within your query and be a little easier to debug, since you can run the inner query (uh) independently and evaluate its results.

```
with uh as (
  select
    u.id, u.name, uh.status, uh.created_date,
    max (uh.created_date) over (partition by uh.user_id) as max_date
  from
    users u,
    user_history uh
  where
    u.id = uh.user_id
)
select
  id, name, status
from uh
where created_date = max_date
```

-- Edit --

For what it's worth, I loaded some sample data:

Users

```
1   Bilbo
2   Fatty
3   Pippin
4   Balin
```

User History

```
1   one     1/1/2014
1   two     1/2/2014
1   three   1/3/2014
2   four    1/4/2014
2   five    1/5/2014
2   six     1/6/2014
3   seven   1/7/2014
3   eight   1/8/2014
3   nine    1/9/2014
```

This was the output:

```
1   Bilbo   three
2   Fatty   six
3   Pippin  nine
```

Here is the row_number alternative if you have multiple history records with the exact same "date" field.

```
with uh as (
  select
    u.id, u.name, uh.status,
    row_number() over 
       (partition by u.id order by uh.created_date desc) as rn
  from
    users u,
    user_history uh
  where
    u.id = uh.user_id
)
select
  id, name, status
from uh
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Hmmm ... shouldn't "u.user_id = uh.id" be "u.id = uh.user_id" ? Regardless, after making that small change what I get back is a list of all users and all user history entries, not the most recent one.

Comment: Really?  The created_date = max_date should have limited this to only the most recent user history record...  that's curious.  If the history entries have multiple records for the same date, then the row_number analytic would work to find "a" most recent, not necesarily "the" most recent.  And yes, you were right about the id fields...  I didn't actually try to create tables and populate with data before writing this.

Comment: Thanks for putting so much work into this. I already accepted T.S.'s answer because it answered my initial question. But I am going to take another look at your answer since the actual query has other stuff in it (which neither he nor you knew about) which is causing his solution not to work. I will get back to you!!

Comment: That's great -- I'm glad you at least got that piece of it working.  For what it's worth, I really discourage the use of scalars in queries.  I'm not saying you should never use them, but it is a rare occasion you can't do it without a scalar, and the performance difference can be quite significant.  When your data goes from thousands to hundreds of thousands or millions, you'll really notice a difference.

Comment: Sorry to ask a dumb question. You said above "It would also eliminate the scalar within your query", and "I really discourage the use of scalars in queries". Can you please explain what you mean by "scalar"?

Comment: By scalar, I mean any time where you have select x, y, (select z... at which point it's implicit that the "select z" returns only one row.  The "one row" from the query within the select is the "scalar" reference.  They work, but they can be performance hogs when they actually execute the query for each row.  Indexes can help mask/mitigate the performance hit.  Again, I'm not saying you should NEVER do it, but it's been a rare occasion I couldn't get a better performing, more transparent, easier to debug query by eliminating the scalar.

Comment: Also, I was referring to scalars in the select clause.  In the where clause, I've never had an issue using scalars or correlated subqueries.

Comment: @RobertBowen Late to the party, I was about to say that Common Table Expression that used in this answer is not necessary better performing. As a matter of fact, it is most likely to execute by the same execution plan as one in my answer. But I agree on `select` as column expression - these are horrible. You may not see much problem on 1000 rows, but if your data has thousands or hundred thousands of rows, it is going to kill you. You better do join